# Prevent Caching a Block in Drupal 7 while using boost module

Tags: drupal, caching, adsense

I want to use Boost module (http://drupal.org/project/boost) for drupal 7 site that runes adsense module too (http://drupal.org/project/adsense). This module allows adsense revenue sharing feature and for example if the revenue sharing is 50%, the adsense block which is a php block, needs to run every time for every visitor and it should not be cached. Now i want to know how can i prevent this block from being cached if i want to all other parameters of pages to be cached by Boost module except this block?
I also have checked following guides but i can't use them. Do you have any suggestion to be able to use Boost module for caching pages and having a dynamic block which contains adsense ads for Drupal 7?
drupal.org/node/583264#whoonline
groups.drupal.org/node/24825

Comment: Boost is caching the final html of the page so you can't "prevent" it from caching the block. 
If the php code you are using is the code that used in block visibility settings, you can try choosing a small cache time so the php code runs frequently. 
But ultimately/unfortunately this is not possible with Boost.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but its doable and i have read some other threads is drupal.org website that are explaining the way of showing i.e latest visitors while using boost module. but i am honestly don't know how to use that guide at all and i am looking for an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your eye on ESI http://drupal.org/project/esi once AJXA rendering has been ported to 7.x (its in 6.x) this should easily be doable.

Comment: Thanks a lot mikeytown2. But can you please explain more? I installed this module but what should i do now to prevent caching special block? Please explain a bit more.

Comment: In ajax mode it will grab the block via ajax. The page html remains the same but now it gets the block via a ajax call.

Comment: Thanks again but i still don't see any ajax mode on the settings of this module. How and where should i enable ajax mode? Please explain a little more.